# Finding an algorithm/strategy for a hotel riddle

Tags: algorithm

I have a problem that i'm currenty trying to solve. 
Let's say we drive a road and we know there are 10 hotels on the way. Each hotel has from 0 to 6 stars. 
My problem is: find a best solution of choosing the most-starred hotel. The only catch is: you cannot turn back and visit hotels you already decided not to visit. 
Is there any way of finding a hotel with a "good" ammount of stars?

I realise there is no way of staying in the hotel with the most stars, what I'm looking for is a strategy for getting a "good or best" hotel.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We could imagine an application that will be interfaced with something like tripadvisor. It would be more simple if they provide web services, but i don't think

Comment: you could somehow have a minimum value depending on how many hotels you've already observed. e.g. if you see the first hotel and it has 5 or 6 stars you accept it, otherwise you go on because there are 9 more hotels that could have a very good amount of stars... at the end, when there are only a few hotels left this threshold should be lower because the risk is to high that the last ones have less stars.

Comment: Do we know anything about distribution? E.g. the probability of a hotel having sertain number of stars is uniform or normal (Bernulli in the case).

Comment: I think from a mathematical point of view it depends a lot on the distribution of the stars (in reality there wouldn't be many 6 star hotels, but a lot with 0 or 1 stars...). And it also depends what the reward is for more stars. Because if the probability is very high that there are many 0 star hotels, and the reward is linear I would simply take the first hotel with more than 0 stars. If the stars are uniform distributed and the reward for more stars is exponentially, I would risk driving further... You see?

Comment: we assume that the probability is the same everywhere

Comment: Define 'good' amount of stars.

Comment: I think the answer will depend upon how much risk you are willing to take.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the [Secretary problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem). Under the assumption that the hotels show up in a random order, the optimal strategy is to drive past 37% of the hotels and then take the next one that is better than all seen so far (or take the last one).